# How to get different overloads for rvalue and lvalue references with a template-deduced type?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, rvalue-reference, forwarding-reference

I have a function `foo` taking a parameter by reference, and I want it to act differently on rvalue and on lvalue references. (I should also mention `foo()` respects constness; it doesn't change the refered-to value.) I know that if I write:

```
template <typename T> foo(T&& x);
```

I've declared a [forwarding reference](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers), rather than an rvalue reference, meaning that this way:

```
template <typename T> foo(const T& x);
template <typename T> foo(T&& x);
```

likely won't get me what I want.

So, my question is: What's the right way to affect different behavior between the two kinds of references?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want to do, such that a forwarding reference isn't what you want?

Comment: @Barry: Allocate heap space for an rvalue reference, allocate nothing for lvalue reference - so that they can be used in some kind of callback.

Comment: Isn't the normal way to do this to demand that if users want a reference to a handler, they pass it in a std::ref?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tag dispatching is the simplest solution.

```
namespace details {
  template <typename T>
  void foo(std::true_type is_lvalue, const T& x) {
    std::cout << x << " is an lvalue\n";
  }
  template <typename T>
  void foo(std::false_type is_lvalue, T&& x) {
    std::cout << x << " is an rvalue\n";
  }
}
template <typename T>
void foo(T&& t) {
  return details::foo(
    typename std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::type{},
    std::forward<T>(t)
  );
}
```

SFINAE is serious overkill when you don't actually want to support neither version being selected for overload resolution purposes.

Answer (score 13):

You can have an lvalue reference overload and a forwarding reference overload:

```
template <typename T> void foo(T& ) { ... }
template <typename T> void foo(T&& ) { ... }
```

For lvalues, the first overload is favored. For rvalues, only the second overload is viable.

---

If what you want is one const lvalue reference overload and one non-const rvalue reference overload, then you just have to add a constraint to the forwarding reference case:

```
template <typename T> void foo(T const& ) { ... }
template <typename T, REQUIRES(!std::is_reference<T>::value)>
void foo(T&& ) { ... }
```

where `REQUIRES` is the method of your choice. Now, for our four cases:

- non-const, lvalue: only 1st is viable
- const lvalue: only 1st is viable
- non-const, rvalue: both viable, 2nd is better match
- const rvalue: both viable, 2nd is <s>more specialized</s> better match

Comment: I up-voted, because this is the easiest most straightforward way. But the OP will have to reconsider their const correctness, [or else this will happen](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45b60c6b9915ce3f).

Comment: You removed the const from the first variant. Was that intentional, and if so - can you elaborate in light of @StoryTeller's comment?

Comment: @StoryTeller I don't have `const` in the first overload?

Comment: The first line has `foo(T&)` and can take a non-const lvalue. But ok, that's still pretty good if I'm not peevish about constness. Or I could check inside with `std::is_const`.

Comment: Well, the OP wanted a `foo(const T& x);`, while this one isn't. But given that Clang and GCC differ with regard to my own answer. I'm starting to doubt what overload resolution *should* do here.

Comment: @StoryTeller OP simply asks to differentiate lvalues and rvalues. Also, `foo(identity<T>&&)` is still a forwarding reference because `identity<T>` *is* `T` (both gcc 7.2 and clang 5.0 think this way, at least).

Comment: @Barry - Yeah, the whole equivalence issue is annoying (and to me, confusing at times).

Comment: @StoryTeller Added an alternative version to do the other case.

Comment: In all rvalue cases, the second is a better match. Partial ordering doesn't come into play.

Answer (score 2):

You can use tag dispatching for c++11 or `if constexpr` for c++17. Something like that.

```
template <typename T> 
void foo(T&& x)
{
    foo(std::addressof(x), typename std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::type{});
}
void foo(void const *value, std::true_type)
{
   // do something on lvalue
}
void foo(void const *value, std::false_type)
{
   // do something on rvalue
}
```

You need to save info about that type although to `reinterpret_cast` that pointer later. Or better as suggested:

```
template <typename T> 
void foo(T&& x)
{
    foo(std::forward<T>(x), typename std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::type{});
}
template <typename T>
void foo(T &&value, std::true_type)
{
   // do something on lvalue
}
template <typename T>
void foo(T &&value, std::false_type)
{
   // do something on rvalue
}
```

Comment: So now we have two helper functions with no type information? -1.

Comment: I agree, better use another template.

Comment: So, why don't you just keep the second variant in your answer?

Comment: For example: helper functions can't reside in header files for some reason and so can't be templates.

Comment: either you need `typename` or drop `::type` no?  `::type` seems like a dependent type.  And you are missing a `)`.

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed since this question, since C++17 things are a little better :) (depending how you like this pattern).

This can be achieved without any funny business with `std::enable_if` however, its just puts the funny business elsewhere, but I like it more:

```
template <typename T>
struct Fn
{
    Fn(T &&);
    Fn(T const & v);
};
```

The two constructors are the overloads of your templated type. If you need to return a value just store it in the class and add a conversion operator. The constructors are used by compiler to deduce class template type.

Downside is, you need to run it with braces instead of brackets.

And ofcourse, a link to play around with:
https://godbolt.org/z/oNzURY

---

Same pattern does work with C++11, but ehh, not as nicely:

```
template <typename T>
bool Foo(T && value)
{
    return Fn<typename std::decay<T>::type>(std::forward<T>(value));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6yvf7W

Comment: This answer uses C++17; the question was about C++11. Please qualify your answer.

Comment: Qualified and added a C++11 version which enables the same functions to be used. The idea here is that you can use the class constructor pattern with C++11 or 17 and when C++17 is avaliable for whoever, change the wrapper to just allow deduction of T.