# Overload rvalue and lvalue reference for template deduced type with return value and its implementation

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, overloading, rvalue-reference

There are a lot of similar questions here on SO (e.g.: [How to get different overloads for rvalue and lvalue references with a template-deduced type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46935605/how-to-get-different-overloads-for-rvalue-and-lvalue-references-with-a-template)), but not exactly this one. In particular, no questions are concered with value returning functions. Furthermore, I am not sure (euphemestically spoken) whether I understood the answers correctly.

---

I want to provide two versions of a function, which either return a new object or change the passed object (and return the changed object -- for consistency). For simplicity I present my code using a unique like algorithm.

User code

```
auto vec = std::vector<int>{1,3,5,2,4};
auto vec1 = tt::unique( vec );  
  // does not change vec and returns new vector
  // vec1 should be {1,2,3,4,5}
  // vec should be {1,3,5,2,4}

auto vec2 = tt::unique( std::move(vec) );  
  // does change vec and returns new vector vec2
  // vec2 should be {1,2,3,4,5}
  // vec should be empty
```

Implementation:

```
namespace tt {
    template< typename T > T unique( T && vec ) {
        std::sort( vec.begin(), vec.end() );
            vec.erase(
            std::unique( vec.begin(), vec.end()),
            vec.end()
        );
        return std::move( vec );
    }
    template< typename T > T unique( T & vec ) {
        return unique( T(vec) );
    }
}
```

To avoid code duplication the lvalue reference version calls the rvalue reference version.

My main questions:

- Is this correct?
- I think by calling the rvalue reference version from the lvalue reference version, I do one extra move.
- Apart from this extra move, do I make any other unnecessary constructions?
- Given the extra move, for very simple algorithms (oneliners), is it more efficient to duplicate the code? E.g. a *sort* above function I would implement as

  ```
  template< typename T > T sort( T & array ) {
      T array_ = array;
      std::sort( array_.begin(), array_.end() );
      return array_;
  }
  ```

  Is this efficient/correct code?

Extra questions:

- Why is this overload never used and why does is compile at all, given that c is const.

  ```
  template< typename T >
  T unique( const T && c ) {
      std::cout << "Rvalue reference unique wrapper!\n";
      return unique( T(c) );
  }
  ```
- Actually I would like to have const in the lvalue reference signature, i.e. something like
  `template<typename T> T unique( const T & vec );`. But, as I read, since the first is a *forwarding reference*, this does not work.

  Thus, what do I have to do to get const correctness here (My question is about C++14, but I am also interrested in C++17 answers).

Comment: One question by question.

Comment: I would simply have `template <typename T> [[nodiscard]] T unique(T vec)`.

Comment: RVO of `return unique( T(vec) );` is optional in C++14, mandatory in C++17.

Comment: The first template function uses a forwarding reference, and not an rvalue reference (which also answers the 1st "extra" question). `&&` is overloaded, in template context, in a non-intuitive way. The best bet here (with C++17) is a single template with a forwarding reference, and an `if constexpr` that figures out what `T` is, and proceeds accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the magic of reference collapsing...

```
 template<class T>
 [[nodiscard]] std::decay_t<T> unique(T&& t) {
   std::decay_t<T> vec=std::forward<T>(t);
   std::sort( vec.begin(), vec.end() );
   vec.erase(
       std::unique( vec.begin(), vec.end() ),
       vec.end()
   );
   return vec;
}
```

works for both cases.  DRY.

Note that view types, like std span, have issues.

Comment: One extra move for temporary, `template <typename T> T unique(T t)` is even better :)

Comment: @jarod with nrvo same number of moves; cannot elide from function argument.

Comment: I still forget than nrvo cannot apply to function argument :/ so no extra moves, indeed. by value seems simpler anyway :)

Comment: What is the use of `std::decay` here? While it seems logical, I tested the code without any `decay`, with `decay` in the return type, with two `decays`. The output is exactly the same for my tests.

Comment: @tomm when T is a reference, we want values.  Both to return and to modify locally.  Test with lvalue ref arg.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I tried it. with std::decay only in the body it does not work. But apart from that (the other two possibilites) it seems to work. In parituclar, I did not manage to get a reference as a return value. How do I have to call my function to get an lvalue reference back?

Comment: @tommsch With no decay, `T foo(T&& t){return t;}` returns a reference when passed an lvalue, like `std::vector<int> x; auto& y = foo(x); assert(&y == &x);`

Answer (score 2):

> My main questions:

> Is this correct?

Implementation is correct.

> I think by calling the rvalue reference version from the lvalue reference version, I do one extra move.

Against

```
template <typename T>
[[nodiscard]] T unique(const T& orig)
{
    T vec{orig};
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    vec.erase(std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end()), vec.end());
    return vec;
}
```

Your `std::move(vec)` disallows [NRVO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), so you have a forced move.

`return vec;` allows NRVO. if not applied, there is a ([automatic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return#Automatic_move_from_local_variables_and_parameters)) move (your version version as also one (explicit) move); if applied, there are no move.

So potentially one extra move indeed.

In C++20, you might get rid of `std::move`, as automatic move can be done from rvalue reference too.

> Apart from this extra move, do I make any other unnecessary constructions?

In case of temporary, you have a forced-move (see above)

With (unique overload)

```
template <typename T>
[[nodiscard]] T unique(T vec)
{
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    vec.erase(std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end()), vec.end());
    return vec;
}
```

NRVO can apply, and if so no extra move. (if not applied one move as your).

And for lvalue object, you also have one copy.

> Given the extra move, for very simple algorithms (oneliners), is it more efficient to duplicate the code?

As shown above, calling rvalue version from lvalue version might have one extra move.

but the unique version doesn't have that overhead and avoid duplication of code.

Note: [`[[nodiscard]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard) is C++17, and seems really appropriate here (especially in your version with reference)

Comment: Thanks for [[nodiscard]]. Without it the user indeed may expect that the input is modified by reference.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to make the "non-move" version accepting `const&` as well. This allows the use the coping version for `const` objects.

Is there a need to *force* the caller to hand-off owner-ship of vec? I would propose to "just" use a `T&`. You can see similar implementations on the stream-operators.

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, foo)
```

> I think by calling the rvalue reference version from the lvalue reference version, I do one extra move.

Yes, there is an extra move, but compared to the copy it is negligible mostly. It would be the the simplest/best way to avoid code duplication. But you can avoid id by using a reference. I'll show in my proposal.

You maybe kick-out copy-elision when you `std::move`. With separate code for the non-move version, you would set T on the stack and return at the end. The compiler would put the return value on the caller stack, so no move or copy would take place.

> Apart from this extra move, do I make any other unnecessary constructions

Since your return type is `T` you force a copy on the return of `unique (T& vec)`

My suggested change:

```cpp
namespace tt {
    template< typename T > T& unique( T& vec ) {
        std::sort( vec.begin(), vec.end() );
            vec.erase(
            std::unique( vec.begin(), vec.end()),
            vec.end()
        );
        return vec;
    }
    template< typename T > T unique( T const& vec ) {
        T r(vec);
        unique( r );
        return r; // support copy elision
    }
}
```

For "copy elision" there is a nice article on the cpp-standard:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: With your suggestion, temporary bind to const lvalue, so you have extra copy (which is worst than extra move).

Comment: Since unique needs modifying an imutable value, there is a need to copy anyway. The author did it `return unique( T(vec) );` which calls the copy-ctor and moves it as temporary. So.. there is no way to get rid of the copy.

Comment: I mean for `unique(std::vector<int>{1, 3, 5, 4, 2});`, OP does extra move, you do extra copy.

Comment: In addition, You break OP example: `auto vec1 = tt::unique( vec );  // does not change vec and returns new vector // vec should be {1,3,5,2,4}`

Comment: Look closely: `unique(std::vector<int>{1, 3, 5, 4, 2});` will call ctor on both versions. On OPs version it happens at `return unique( T(vec) );` --> `T(vec)` will create a copy.
Yes you're right. `vec1` would be changed. OP would need to call `auto vec1 = unique(static_cast<const T>(vec))` or simply declare vec as const.

Comment: *"On OPs version it happens at `return unique( T(vec) );`"*. No, the other overload is chosen, `unique( T && vec )` is a only viable match.

Comment: I tested this, because I didnt think this works, and indeed, it does not work.